# Can we use existing Hdfs with Cloudera cluster which is not part of Cloudera Distributed Hadoop?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing, cloudera

Is there a way to using existing Apache Hdfs with creating new Cloudera Cluster and how to connect them?

Comment: Curious, why would you do this, exactly?

Comment: We have existing hdfs but we need to move it to CDH

Comment: I think it would be a lot more straightforward for you to just move your data between clusters via distcp.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply i will try your suggestion